# Why does Typescript compiler not change .ts to .js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

In the image below on the left in the folders you can see my **/src** Typescript (blue) compiled into my **/dist** (purple) Javascript using tsc.

[image]

You can see in the source file on the left that references a .ts module file that it isn't compiled into referencing a .js module file on the right.

Why not? How could the Javascript possibly run if tsc doesn't convert references?

Second question: I then tried manually changing the compiled reference from **.ts** to **.js** and running **node dist/server.js** but I get the error *cannot find module tools/typescriptImport.js'*. Why does node fail to find the module when it is correctly referenced (and you can see on the far right that it is a module)?

Comment: From the `import` declaration, try removing the `.ts` extension and set the path to `./tools/typescriptImports`. The preferred way to without the extension so it's `extension agnostic`.

Comment: As expected, tsc then leaves the line unchanges in the .js output, with no extension. But node still can't find the module.

Comment: Most of the times, this problem is solved by adding a `.d.ts` file. Try creating a simple `typescriptImports.d.ts` file and reference it.

Comment: Did you try the relative path as I told you?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the './', nor thought it makes a difference. It works now, thanks. I'll mark your answer as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you have to remove the `.ts` extension from the `import`. TypeScript says that it treats it as a static string and won't change it.

Second, out of experience, I guess using a `.d.ts` file may solve your `module not found` error. I have solved many times by using this small hack. You can reference it using `/// <reference path="tools/typeScriptImports.d.ts" />`. Imagine `.d.ts` as the header file for TypeScript.

Lastly, try and make the path relative to the `server.js` file. So: `./tools/typeScriptImports`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to write extension `.ts` in `import` commands.

Corresponding documentation: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external

Comment: Thanks. And can you see any reason why node can't find the module when it runs the js?

Comment: Try to change your path in the transpiled JS file to a relative path. (e.g. `var moduleA = require( "./module-a.js" );`)