# Compile Typescript to native browser ES modules

Tags: typescript, tsc, es6-modules

How can you compile Typescript to work with browsers that support [ES modules](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)?

I'm using `<script type="module">` with `module=es2015` in my tsconfig, but I can't write imports paths that work for the compiler and the runtime.

The browser needs requires fully qualified import paths and Typescript [doesn't convert the import extension during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783953/why-does-typescript-compiler-not-change-ts-to-js).

For example, the following snippet of TS doesn't change during compilation.

```
import foo from "./foo.ts";
import bar from "./bar";
```

When it runs in the browser, it emits two network requests for files that don't exist.

```
GET foo.ts -> (should be) GET foo.js
GET bar -> (should be) GET bar.js
```

Comment: If you're using express, you could specify [`express.static(…, { extensions: ['js'] })`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html#extensions) which would allow the native ES modules to resolve the relative paths to JavaScript files, if you use `import foo from "./foo"`

Answer (score 3):

The only way to achieve this at the moment is to use `.js` in your TypeScript imports (even though the file is technically `.ts`).

```
// index.ts
import foo from "./foo.js";

// foo.ts
export default "foo";
```

This only works in TypeScript 2 and more modern versions. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577) for more context.